# Arrange container content positioning

Tags: css

I have small container with the users name aligned all the way to the left, and as the name becomes larger i want the text to move the left therefore taking up empty space.  How can i do this.

What i have right now:

```
.namelist {
 margin-left:300px;
 }
```

Comment: Can you elaborate or post it on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Whvkw/    Ok you see how the name is all the way to the right.  Now thats how i will be organizing the names all the way to the right.  If the names exceeds that lenght it should starting moving the name the left side rather than adding a new line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me know if this helps

```
.namelist {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: that actually exceeds the width of the box but it moves text to the right rather than the left

Comment: is right this should do it, you could use float: right; as well depending on your overall design.

Comment: @mashapplabs float:right did the trick.  Thansk to both of you.

Comment: @AAA I thought you will be organizing the names all the way to the right, that's why text is aligned to the right. You can also use floats as @mashappslabs mentioned. Again, unless you give us more code we wont' be able to see what you are seeing since you mentioned it exceeds the width of the box. We don't know which box you are talking about.